# CNAME not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cname-record

I've got a domain (`example.com`) registered with godaddy and pointed to nameservers hosted by linode. I've got a multisite WordPress install on linode (`blogs.com`) and I want to point the domain to a subdomain of the wordpress install (`example.com -> example.blogs.com`).

The subdomain of the wordpress install works fine - DNS can find it and I can browse to it.  in the linode's DNS manager I've set up a CNAME to make the pointer I referenced above.

Whois shows that the linode nameservers are set for the domain, but DNS can't find any nameserver for example.com.

Am I missing a step, or do I have something misconfigured?

**EDIT 1**

The answer section of the dig request using one of linode's nameservers is

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 44359
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

The answer section from the dig using my host's nameserver is

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 16379
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

Same response in the status field if I specify CNAME or just accept the standard A query.

I do not have an A record for that example.com on the linode nameservers; do I need to set that up?

This is a fairly recent change - a few hours ago, so maybe I'm just being impatient? The nameserver changes made at the same time came through pretty quickly. I figured that the CNAME entry would be simultaneous with that; am I wrong in that expectation?

Comment: Work backwards a little. First ensure the A record that your CNAME points to works first. Fix that and your CNAME should also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically what you're asking for is invalid.  `CNAME` [conflicts with all other records](http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1176) ([with a special exception for DNSSEC records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#Restrictions)), thus having `CNAME xxxxx` conflicts with the `SOA`, `MX`, `NS` etc records for the domain.  My guess is that the reason the domain resolves when you use an `A` there and fails when you use CNAME is because the DNS server enforces those restrictions and is unable to process your zone file.

Furthermore, based on your response to @xwincftwx's question, it's not clear that getting CNAME to work would do what you want in the first place.  A `CNAME` pointing to an `A` record is *exactly* the same as an `A` record in the first place.  The CNAME is handled entirely internally by the DNS system and the web browser only sees the IP address.  In your test with an `A` record (let's say 1.2.3.4), the browser connected to `1.2.3.4` and asked it for the website `example.com`.  If that server isn't configured to serve a website for `example.com` it typically serves a default site (in this case `blogs.com`).

*If* you got your domain to work as a `CNAME`, the browser would ask for the IP address of `example.com`.  DNS would see that it is a `CNAME`, look up `example.blogs.com` and return `1.2.3.4`.  The browser would connect to `1.2.3.4` and ask it for `example.com` just as it did when it was an `A` record.

If you want people going to `example.com` to be redirected to `example.blogs.com` then you'll need to set up a basic web server that receives connections to `example.com` and sends a 301 permanent redirect to the browser to tell it go to `example.blogs.com`

Comment: very cogent explanation of what's going on; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a CNAME for the root record in a zone file (this is prohibited per RFC 1034, read section 3.6.2). You'll need to put in an A record instead that points to the same IP as the target of your CNAME rule.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `dig example.com`? If your know your nameserver's IP you can force dig to use your nameserver (`dig @nameserver-ip example.com`). If this works, your nameserver is not used for example.com. When did you assign the linode nameservers? Those changes can take time. Especially if your ISP's DNS server caches results...

Comment: If some changes came through, all of them should have come through. I'm not sure about the need for an A record. My mistake with a CNAME record was the missing tailing ".". So `@ IN CNAME example.blogs.com.`. But the SERVFAIL does not seem right (as well as "REFUSED"). The SERVFAIL problem is mentiond [here](www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/bind9-dig-x-returns-status-servfail-643191/c), the REFUSED problems also points to wrong configuration of the nameserver. As if you were not allowed to query.

Answer (score 0):

Just looks like that your nameserver isnt running.

Can you check if you name server is running.

ps -aux | grep named

If your nameserver is not running.. start it and check again.

If it isnt started after you started it.. please post the named information of /var/log/daemon and /var/log/messages

grep named /var/log/messages
grep named /var/log/daemon

Perhaps it is a misconfiguration in your zone file.

if your nameserver IS RUNNING, please check your named.conf if your zone accept all incomming traffic.

It is not required to include A records of example.com in your zone file but it is recommended to do for DNS checks and whois checks.

Comment: I should have been more explicit; I'm using Linode's nameservers (ns[1-4].linode.com) and their DNS manager. Their servers are running, the zone files pass a check and have the trailing "." Moreover, when I do add an 'A' record for example.com, nslookup finds it within 15 minutes. Of course then example.com is pointed to blogs.com, not example.blogs.com.